# Extract value from .json and pass to powershell script

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-devops

I'm trying to extract the operationId value from my json file and substitute it into my powershell script for further deployment, but it keeps failing.
Here is my powershell script example:

```
 # Set variables
 $ApiMgmtRG = "MyResourceGroup"
 $ApiMgmtServiceName = "MyApiManagementService"
 $ApiId = "MyApiId"
 
 # Connect to API Management context
 $apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $ApiMgmtRG -ServiceName $ApiMgmtServiceName
 
 # Get all operationIds for the API
 $operationIds = Get-Content .\OpenAPISpecification.json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OperationId
 
 # Loop through each operationId and execute the Set-AzApiManagementPolicy cmdlet
 foreach ($operationId in $operationIds) {
     Set-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $apimContext -ApiId $ApiId -OperationId **$operationId** -PolicyFilePath **$operationId**.xml -Format application/vnd.ms-azure-apim.policy.raw+xml
 }
```

Here is my json file example:

```
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "paths": {
        "/v1/test": {
            "get": {
                "description": "test.",
                **"operationId"**: "test1",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "description": "test.",
                        "in": "query",
                        "name": "clientId",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                ],
             }
```

It's just part of my big json file, but the structure is the same. I'm trying to extract all operationIds and substitute them in the deployment step to the API management.
Can you please tell me where I made a mistake in my script?

Comment: Getting all the `operationId` values will not be as straight forward. We will need a valid Json that represents the one you have to give a proper answer. with the Json you're showing the path to get that value will be something like `$json.paths.PSObject.Properties.Value.get.operationId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script solved my problem:

```
    $operationIds = Get-Content myjson.json -Raw |
    Select-String -pattern '"operationId":\s*"?([^",]+)"?,?' -allmatches |
        Foreach-Object { $_.Matches |
            Foreach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }
        }
foreach ($operationId in $operationIds) {
    Set-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $apimContext -ApiId $ApiId -OperationId "$operationId" -PolicyFilePath "$operationId.xml" -Format application/vnd.ms-azure-apim.policy.raw+xml
}
```